# How to assign form name to variable as string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, attributes

```
if($(currentTab+' form.dataform').attr('name') !== undefined)
    var $selectedTab = $(currentTab+' form.dataform').attr('name');
else  
var selectedTab = '0';
```

alert($(selectedTab)); Gives me an object. I need string. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the $() around the selectedTab, and remove the $ from the variable definition.

```
if($(currentTab+' form.dataform').attr('name') !== undefined)
    var selectedTab = $(currentTab+' form.dataform').attr('name');
else  
    var selectedTab = '0';

alert(selectedTab);
```

Comment: Thanks, and one more thing: var $selectedTab >> var selectedTab

Comment: I actually did say that, but not clearly.  I'll edit to improve clarity.